# TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"storyFile"' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to upgrade an old React Typescript project and still running into problems.

I resolved not having a constructor with the ! after each class level variable. Now it's complaining about the storyFile parameter. This is from the GitHub repo fyrevm-web. For the exact file see: https://github.com/ChicagoDave/fyrevm-web/blob/master/src/FyreVMWeb/FyreVMMem.ts

Any clues?

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"storyFile"' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property 'storyFile' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS7053

    25 |             this.wrapper = FyreVM.EngineWrapper.loadFromArrayBuffer(storyFile, true);
    26 |             this.ProcessCommand(this.wrapper.run());
  > 27 |             this.FyreVMData['storyFile'] = storyFile;
       |             ^
    28 |             this.FyreVMData['quetzalData'] = this.wrapper.saveGame();
    29 |             return this.FyreVMData;
    30 |         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the properties you're trying to assign on the `FyreVMData` type.

```
FyreVMData: {
  storyFile: ArrayBuffer;
  quetzalData: any; // or whatever the type `this.wrapper.saveGame()` returns
};
```

Comment: I think I'll stop here. There are way too many problems and it's likely the dependent lib glulx-typescript needs to be upgraded as well. I'll need to pay someone to do this work.

Comment: you can turn off some type checks if you think you can't solve them all at once. For this particular case you can set `noImplicitAny = false` in your tsconfig.json file

Comment: I figured there was a "cheat", but I think I want the whole thing cleaned up anyway. Already posted a gig on Upwork.

Comment: I can help you out

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message carefully

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"storyFile"' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property 'storyFile' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS7053
```

Now, let's have a closer look at your code:

```
 // the type of this variable is {}
 FyreVMData: {};

 // ...after some lines, you have
 this.FyreVMData['storyFile'] = storyFile;
 this.FyreVMData['quetzalData'] = this.wrapper.saveGame();
```

The type of the `FyreVMData` is `{}` but you are trying to insert keys `storyFile` and `quetzalData` which are not there in type `{}`

To solve this, you first need to know the type of `FyreVMData`.

1. If the `FyreVMData` variable has predefined keys, then use following

```
FyreVMData: {
  storyFile: ArrayBuffer;
  quetzalData: any; // or what is returned by this.wrapper.saveGame();
};
```

2. If you want to insert dynamic keys into your `FyreVMData` object, then you need to define your object as follows

```
// the key of FyreVMData object will be string, and value will be any
// you can modify the type of key/value based on your requirement.
FyreVMData: { [key: string]: any }

// now we can add dynamic keys to our FyreVMData object as follows:

FyreVMData["name"] = "stackoverflow"
FyreVMData["value"] = {}
```

If you want to allow implicit any you can update your tsconfig like this

```json
noImplicitAny: false
```